# connecting open vswitch with two virtual machines

Tags: linux, mininet, sdn, openflow, openvswitch

I'm running an Open VSwitch on a VirtualBox VM, 
i want to connect 2 VMs that are running on VirtualBox into OpenVswitch. i did these things:

1)first i made an VM running ubuntu (lubuntu), and installed ovs using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install openvswitch-switch
```

2)after that i defined 2 adapter on vm and determine them as `Internal Network` cause vms want to connect to these machine internally from virtual box

but how can i connect 2 virtualbox's VMs that are running on separate subnets (`10.1.1.1 and 10.1.2.1`) using this OVS?
the diagram is as follow:
http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/10986491/L.png

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to use OVS in this case, though you can achieve this by providing gateway ip.

[image]

Say suppose you have create internal network with subnet 192.170.10.0/24 as internal1 and other internal2 with subnet 192.170.20.0/24

**Configuration on VM1:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.170.10.10
network 192.170.10.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.10.255
gateway 192.170.10.20
```

**Configuration on VM2:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.170.20.10
network 192.170.20.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.20.255
gateway 192.170.20.20
```

**Configuration on OVS:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.170.10.20
network 192.170.10.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.10.255
gateway 192.170.10.20

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.170.20.20
network 192.170.20.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.20.255
gateway 192.170.20.20
```

Using above configuration you can ping between VMs on different subnet

---

However if you still want to use OVS, here is way to configure.

**Configuration on VM1:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.170.10.10
network 192.170.10.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.10.255
```

**Configuration on VM2:**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.170.20.10
network 192.170.20.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.170.20.255
```

**Configuration on OVS:**

1. Set interface to load to manual in `/etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet manual

   auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet manual
   ```
2. Create Two bridges

   ```
   sudo ovs-vsctl add-br vm1-br
   sudo ovs-vsctl add-br vm2-br
   ```
3. Add respective ports.

   ```
   sudo ovs-vsctl add-port vm1-br eth0
   sudo ovs-vsctl add-port vm2-br eth1
   ```
4. Bridge the bridges using patch interface

   ```
   sudo ovs-vsctl add-port vm1-br patch1
   sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch1 type=patch
   sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch1 options:peer=patch2

   sudo ovs-vsctl add-port vm1-br patch2
   sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch2 type=patch
   sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch2 options:peer=patch1
   ```
5. Bring up the bridges

   ```
   sudo ifconfig vm1-br up
   sudo ifconfig vm-br up
   ```
6. Set the IP Address

   ```
   sudo ifconfig vm1-br 192.170.10.20/24
   sudo ifconfig vm2-br 192.170.20.20/24
   ```
7. Now you can ping  between VMs

Comment: Sometimes you need OVS, for example on my network I will use one VM running a SDN controller, one VM for the Openvswitch and then 2 VMs running hosts connected to the switch. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: With this program, I can ping from the Openvswitch to both VMs but not between VMs. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Can you please explain bit please.